# window telegram webapp - how can i adapt window telegram webapp to react and typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, web-applications, window, telegram

I can't match window.telegram.webApp to typescript in react. Has anyone used this in a real project? A github link would be great! I use plain javascript no problem, I couldn't do it in typescript

how to add new property to window on typescript like type Telegram ={...} and window.Telegram = Telegram

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.